# How can i use a trackBar scroll event to move between images fast and smooth?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the scroll event

```
int countver = 0;
        int counthor = 0;
        Image newImage;
        private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
            {
                newImage = Image.FromFile(files[files.Length - 1]);
                float imghorizontal = newImage.HorizontalResolution;
                float imgvertical = newImage.VerticalResolution;
                if (trackBar2.Value < trackBar2.Maximum)
                {
                    countver += 100;
                    counthor += 100;
                }
                if (trackBar2.Value == trackBar2.Maximum)
                {
                    countver += 100;
                    counthor += 100;
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = ResizeImage(files[files.Length - 1], (int)imghorizontal + counthor, (int)imgvertical + countver);
                label15.Text = (int)imghorizontal + counthor.ToString() + "," + (int)imgvertical + countver.ToString();
                label15.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

This is the method Resize Image

```
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(String filename, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(filename))
            {
                //Caluate new Size
                int newWidth = originalImage.Width;
                int newHeight = originalImage.Height;
                double aspectRatio = (double)originalImage.Width / (double)originalImage.Height;
                if (aspectRatio <= 1 && originalImage.Width > maxWidth)
                {
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    newHeight = (int)Math.Round(newWidth / aspectRatio);
                }
                else if (aspectRatio > 1 && originalImage.Height > maxHeight)
                {
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newHeight * aspectRatio);
                }
                if (newWidth >= 0 && newHeight >= 0)
                {
                    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    {
                        //--Quality Settings Adjust to fit your application
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
                        return newImage;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is when i move the scroll up or down it's taking a 1-3 seconds to make the image process. And if i move the scroll up faster to another value it's taking even more(another vlaue i mean i'm trying to move the slider from the beginning to the end the program hang).

This is the form1 code i'm using a backgroundworker to change the images size on the hard disk. The whole idea is to give the user a preview of how the image/s will look like and then if he decide it's good enough he click a button that start the backgroundworker.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Images_Batch_Resize
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;
        string[] files;
        string directoryPath;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label6.Visible = false;
            label7.Visible = false;
            label8.Visible = false;
            label9.Visible = false;
            label10.Visible = false;
            label12.Visible = false;
            label15.Visible = false;

            openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            trackBar2.Minimum = 0;
            trackBar2.Maximum = 20;
        }

        private void changeWorkingDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
       + "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff";
            //openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

                try
                {
                    if (files.Length > 0)
                    {
                        label6.Text = files.Length.ToString();
                        label6.Visible = true;
                        directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(files[0]);
                        label12.Text = directoryPath;
                        label12.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox2.Load(files[0]);
                        pictureBox1.Load(files[0]);
                        trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                        trackBar1.Maximum = files.Length - 1;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        private void beginOperationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private static Bitmap ResizeImage(String filename, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(filename))
            {
                //Caluate new Size
                int newWidth = originalImage.Width;
                int newHeight = originalImage.Height;
                double aspectRatio = (double)originalImage.Width / (double)originalImage.Height;
                if (aspectRatio <= 1 && originalImage.Width > maxWidth)
                {
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    newHeight = (int)Math.Round(newWidth / aspectRatio);
                }
                else if (aspectRatio > 1 && originalImage.Height > maxHeight)
                {
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newHeight * aspectRatio);
                }
                if (newWidth >= 0 && newHeight >= 0)
                {
                    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    {
                        //--Quality Settings Adjust to fit your application
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
                        return newImage;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        int countver = 0;
        int counthor = 0;
        Image newImage;
        private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
            {
                newImage = Image.FromFile(files[files.Length - 1]);
                float imghorizontal = newImage.HorizontalResolution;
                float imgvertical = newImage.VerticalResolution;
                if (trackBar2.Value < trackBar2.Maximum)
                {
                    countver += 100;
                    counthor += 100;
                }
                if (trackBar2.Value == trackBar2.Maximum)
                {
                    countver += 100;
                    counthor += 100;
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = ResizeImage(files[files.Length - 1], (int)imghorizontal + counthor, (int)imgvertical + countver);
                label15.Text = (int)imghorizontal + counthor.ToString() + "," + (int)imgvertical + countver.ToString();
                label15.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(files[trackBar1.Value]);
            pictureBox2.Load(files[trackBar1.Value]);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                int counter = 0;
                int percentage = 0;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {                   
                    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(ResizeImage(file, 300, 300));
                    string resizedfilename = Path.Combine(directoryPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + "_resized.jpg");
                    bmp1.Save(resizedfilename);
                    bmp1.Dispose();
                    counter++;
                    percentage = counter * 100 / files.Length;
                    worker.ReportProgress(percentage);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string ttt = err.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        int oldValue = 0;
        private void trackBar2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as TrackBar).Value >= oldValue)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
            oldValue = (sender as TrackBar).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you timed the `Image.FromFile(filename)` call and the `DrawImage` call?  Those are likely to be the speed bottlenecks.  If they take 1-3 seconds (each or together), you know where you're spending your time and you'll have to look into pre-rendering, caching, or other techniques to avoid doing the heavy lifting during the actual scroll.

Comment: a) your if and else clause in the scroll event make no sense. b) why do you talk about moving when you are resizing? c) if all you care about is the display, why not let the system do the work and resize the picturebox with sizemode=Zoom? Accessing the disk is certainly a bad idea, cache or no cache.. How large are the images? d) your zooming works only for square images.

Comment: TaW how should i do it ? The whole idea is to make like a preview to show the user how the image will look like after a resize and if the user like it then i have a button that when i click on it it's starting a backgroundworker making the real change to the images. In a backgroundworker dowork i'm using also the same method ResizeImage but this time i'm also saving it on hard disk as bmp.